# Except when I wash

Tags: riddle

I am always growing,
but I never get any taller.
I am hard
but I can bend.
I can be seen in many colors,
but those colors are not me.
I move often,
but I can't move unassisted.
I cannot feel pleasure or pain.
Unless it's too hot, I rarely see the light of day.
I usually live in darkness, except when I wash.

Comment: hints pls, second last line is bugging me

Comment: @Vikram I'm too late for a hint, someone guessed it :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Toenail

I am always growing,
but I never get any taller.

> They get longer, not taller.

I am hard
but I can bend.

> Obviously.

I can be seen in many colors,
but those colors are not me.

> Due to nail varnish.

I move often,
but I can't move unassisted.

> Walking around does the trick.

I cannot feel pleasure or pain.

> Even scissors won't hurt.

Unless it's too hot, I rarely see the light of day.

> Walking around bare footed.

I usually live in darkness, except when I wash.

> Hard to wash your feet with shoes or socks on.

Comment: Bravo! +1 You got it.